# Dynamic Size Change in Tkinter messing up

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to configure my text to be a certain size if its window size is too large. This is the code I'm using.

```
def res(e):
    h=e.height

    if h>180.0:
        l.config(font=("Cambria",30,"bold"))
    elif h<=180.0:
        l.config(font=("Cambria",20,"bold"))

#configuration
gui.geometry("500x300")
gui.minsize(500, 300)

Grid.rowconfigure(gui, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(gui, 0, weight=1)
Grid.rowconfigure(gui, 1, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(gui, 1, weight=1)
Grid.rowconfigure(gui, 2, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(gui, 2, weight=1)

l=Label(gui, text="Welcome!", pady=20, padx=20)
l.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew", columnspan=3)

gui.bind('<Configure>', res)

#calling GUI
gui.mainloop()
```

(There is a bit more code in the actual program but it's too bulky to post here. This is the portion with the problem.)

There's a particular size of the window in which the text starts alternating between the two sizes rapidly. This also happens every time I move the tkinter window or any time I open it after it has been minimized.

Any idea how I could fix this? I've tried setting the values of height as int instead of float and tried using the else statement instead of elif for the conditions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: As event binding on root window will inherit to its children, so the function will be executed when its children is resized as well.  You can do the font resize only when the function is triggered by resize of root window, i.e. `if event.widget is gui: ...`.

Comment: When you bind the configure event to a container like a toplevel window or a frame, the event handler will be called for the container and again for each widget inside it. This is often undesirable and have unexpected side-effects. There's isn't enough code in your question to tell if this is part of the problem or not.

Comment: Can you make a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Since the provided code doesn't run, it's hard to give decent advice.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the font, set the variable as

```
self.font = SOME_BASE_FONT
self.labelName.config(font = self.font)
```

Then you can use:

```
self.font = tkFont.Font(size = PIXEL_HEIGHT)
```

And finally you can define your callback function to resize as follows:

```
def resize(self, event):
    self.font = tkFont(size = widget_height)
```

Comment: And where does `widget_height` come from?

Comment: `widget_height` is set by whoever uses this code and depends on personal preference

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help.

Two questions --> 
i) tkFony.Font doesn't work on python 3. Do you have an alternative for that?
ii) 'self' is not defined as of yet in my program. Do you have any alternative value to that which I could use?

Comment: @Amabilia it does work, you just need to import it via `import tkFont`, try not to use self and it should still work

Answer (score 0):

As event binding on root window will inherit to its children, so the function will be executed when its children is resized as well. You can do the font resize only when the function is triggered by resize of root window:

```py
def res(e):
    if e.widget is gui:
        fs = 30 if e.height > 180 else 20
        l.config(font=("Cambria",fs,"bold"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. In the `res` function instead of setting `h` to `e.height`, use:

```py
gui.update()
h=gui.winfo_height()
```